# Tell pip to throw an error if package is already installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Is there a way to tell pip to throw an error if a package is already installed. Specifically, if the package is installed using `pip list`, I would like to avoid installing it again / changing its version. I would like to throw an error.

Comment: [`pip install --upgrade-strategy=only-if-needed`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-upgrade-strategy). It's actually the default.

Comment: The answer to your original question is: no. Existing installation is not an error. You can stay with it, you can ignore it, you can force-upgrade it. But you cannot fail over it.